# Case wise using mapping from columns to fill value in another column in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame with multiple columns:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       col1|       col2|       col3|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         s1|         c1|         p3|
|         s2|         c1|         p3|
|         s1|         c3|         p3|
|         s3|         c4|         p4|
|         s4|         c5|         p4|
|         s2|         c6|         p4|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now what I want to achieve is that I want to create a new column from mapping of multiple columns by using let's say a dict (since number of unique values are large, individual or case statements would be tedious). 
The idea is to first map the values of col1, then if there are remaining null values in the new column, to map them from col2, then again if more null values, to map them from col3, and finally the remaining null values to be replaced by a str literal.:

```
col1_map = {'s1' : 'apple', 's3' : 'orange'}
col2_map = {'c1' : 'potato', 'c6' : 'tomato'}
col3_map = {'p3' : 'ball', 'p4' : 'bat'}
```

The final output would look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       col1|       col2|       col3|       col4|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         s1|         c1|         p3|      apple|
|         s2|         c1|         p3|     potato|
|         s1|         c3|         p3|      apple|
|         s3|         c4|         p4|     orange|
|         s4|         c5|         p4|        bat|
|         s2|         c6|         p4|     tomato|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My approach so far is to create a new column. And then to

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*col1_dict.items())])

df = df.withColumn('col4', mapping_expr[df['col4']])
```

This will get the values in col4 from the mapping of col1. however My issue is that if I repeat this for col2, and there's already a mapped value from col1 in col4, the new mapping will replace that. I do not want that.
Does anyone have any suggestion to maintain this order of addition of values in the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did almost right, just that you need to use `mapping_expr` in sucession.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit, when
from itertools import chain
values = [('s1','c1','p3'),('s2','c1','p3'),('s1','c3','p3'),('s3','c4','p4'),('s4','c5','p4'),('s2','c6','p4')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2','col3'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  s1|  c1|  p3|
|  s2|  c1|  p3|
|  s1|  c3|  p3|
|  s3|  c4|  p4|
|  s4|  c5|  p4|
|  s2|  c6|  p4|
+----+----+----+
```

Dictionary, as provided by you and creating it's mapping

```
col1_map = {'s1' : 'apple', 's3' : 'orange'}
col2_map = {'c1' : 'potato', 'c6' : 'tomato'}
col3_map = {'p3' : 'ball', 'p4' : 'bat'}

#Applying the mapping of dictionary.
mapping_expr1 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*col1_map.items())])
mapping_expr2 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*col2_map.items())])
mapping_expr3 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*col3_map.items())])
```

Finally applying [`create_map()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) in succession. All I am doing in addition, is checking if after operating on `col1/col2` we still have null, which can be checked using [`isNull()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.isnull) function.

```
df=df.withColumn('col4', mapping_expr1.getItem(col('col1')))
df=df.withColumn('col4', when(col('col4').isNull(),mapping_expr2.getItem(col('col2'))).otherwise(col('col4')))
df=df.withColumn('col4', when(col('col4').isNull(),mapping_expr3.getItem(col('col3'))).otherwise(col('col4')))
df.show()
+----+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|col3|  col4|
+----+----+----+------+
|  s1|  c1|  p3| apple|
|  s2|  c1|  p3|potato|
|  s1|  c3|  p3| apple|
|  s3|  c4|  p4|orange|
|  s4|  c5|  p4|   bat|
|  s2|  c6|  p4|tomato|
+----+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Looks good to me. It somehow didn't click to me on how to use isNull here. Thanks for the help. I'll check the solution for any errors, if there and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: A suggestion: for readability, change `when(col('col4').isNull(),mapping_expr2.getItem(col('col2'))).otherwise(col('col4')))` to `coalesce(col('col4'), mapping_expr2.getItem(col('col2')))`. Same effect, just shorter. +1